# Семантические теги header, main, footer

Tags: html, html5, семантика

Допускается ли использование тегов (header, main, footer) по отдельности? Например на странице будет присутствовать main и footer, но отсутствовать header. Или же обязательно должна соблюдаться структура: 
- header 
- main 
- footer.

Comment: Не обязательно, это уже на ваш вкус и цвет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допускается, их может быть несколько на странице или вообще не быть. Вырезки из спеки:

**`<header>`**

http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-header-element

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section’s heading
>   (an h1–h6 element), but this is not required. The header element can
>   also be used to wrap a section’s table of contents, a search form, or
>   any relevant logos.

**`<footer>`**

http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-footer-element

> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor main
>   element or sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer
>   typically contains information about its section, such as who wrote
>   it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like.

**`<main>`**

Более того, начиная с HTML 5.2 может быть несколько `main`

http://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#the-main-element

> A document must not have more than one main element that does not have
>   the [§5.1 The hidden attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute specified.